# Can't Install NodeJS 16 with curl

Tags: nodejs, 22.04

I've recently upgraded one of my virtual machines on DigitalOcean with Ubuntu 22.04.

Upon installing Node with the following command I receive an error: "## Your distribution, identified as "jammy", is not currently supported,"

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
```

It is possible to simply install Node with "apt install nodejs" but that gives me a version outdated for the application I'm using.

Are there any good alternitives to installing NodeJS 16.x on Ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend first installing Node Version Manager so you can easily detect and change node as needed, the following would help

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
export NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm;
source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh;
```

from there you just need to

```
nvm install v16
nvm use v16
```